# Can't understand Priority Queue process

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, priority-queue

```
        String S = "aaaaaaaacabbbb";

        if (S == null || S.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (char c : S.toCharArray()) {
            map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        }
        PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> (b.getValue() - a.getValue()));
        pq.addAll(map.entrySet());
        System.out.println(pq);
```

So, I understood that for this particular snippet, highest priority is given to the key with maximum value, when I print the queue, I get

```
[a=9, b=4, c=1]
```

but when I use this comparator

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> (a.getValue() - b.getValue()));
```

I didnt understand why it gives

```
[c=1, a=9, b=4]
```

I thought `b` would be second, and `a` would be last

**2nd problem**

Also, when I added an entry

```
  Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry =
 new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Character, Integer>('a', 5);
            pq.offer(entry);
```

I get this output

```
[c=1, a=5, b=4, a=9]
```

Don't understand how the `a` goes last now

Comment: Use while (!pq.isEmapty()) sysout(pq.remove()); instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting javadoc of [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` is *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue **in any particular order**. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.